# How to measure a specific part of a voltage range using a microprocessor like an Arduino

Tags: arduino, resistors, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I wish to monitor a battery using an Arduino.
I can successfully measure the value using an Arduino via its Analog port, which gives me a 1024 bit value range.

Where I'm stuck is how to allocate that 1024 bits to a small portion of the voltage range to improve the accuracy.

By using a simple resistor divider I can measure the battery voltage from say 14.5V to 0V and the 1024 bit are therefore spread across that.

What I would prefer to do is only measure from 11.5V to 14.5V and have the 1024 bits associated with that range, make it more accurate.

I can't for the life of me think of how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered a differential amplifier, measuring with respect to an offset (e.g. 11.5V)?

Comment: it's 10 bits, not 1024 bits

Comment: Yes it is 1024 values from 10 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5VLAB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit will produce 0-5 VDC with an input of 10-15 VDC.

[image: Battery voltage expander]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and helpful answer, that's exactly what I was after.